# Image shared on linkedin in not loaded in thumbnail, But can see when click on post

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am able to do post my images with description on LinkedIn. But images are not visible on my post.But when i click on my post it redirect me to the image and it is visible.

The example url i am sharing on Linkedin is following:-
http://servers.exampleserver.com:85/myserver/image/showcase/POST/65eec0bd-1e95-45a9-b962-b7c83a3d7605.jpg (This is only example of url)

I think the problem is with url, because when i post image from any other server, then image is visible. 
But i don't know what is wrong with url. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Once you preview a page in a LinkedIn share, that preview remains unchanged for a period of a week.  To quote the documentation...

> ...LinkedIn caches link preview content for 7 days. (Source: [LinkedIn: How to Clear LinkedIn Link Preview Cache](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-clear-linkedin-link-preview-cache-ananda-kannan-p/).)

Refresh the preview cache for your site by going to the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com): This will refresh your content (it only shows the fully refreshed content the second time you inspect).  And, if you still have a problem, the inspector should tell you what it looked at determine which image to show and how it finally made its decision.

You can verify for a fact that caching is the problem by previewing the share page for `example.com?test=1` instead of `example.com`.  By using the new parameter, you'll miss the LinkedIn preview cache, and get a fresh preview.